# A particular generating set of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Is the set of all transpositions starting at $1$, i.e. elements of the form $(1,a),a=1,...,n$, a generating set of $S_n$?

By [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) I know that a generating set of the group $S_n$ is given by the elements of the form $(i,i+1)$. So if I prove that these elements are generated by my elements, it´s over.

Let's consider the permutation $(i,i+1)$.

then:
$$\begin{align}(1,i)(1,i+1)(1,i)(1)&=(1,i)(1,i+1)(i)=(1,i)(i)=1\\
(1,i)(1,i+1)(1,i)(i)&=(1,i)(1,i+1)(1)=(1,i)(i+1)=i+1\\
(1,i)(1,i+1)(1,i)(i+1)&=(1,i)(1,i+1)(i+1)=(1,i)(1)=i\end{align}$$
and
$$(1,i)(1,i+1)(1,i)(j)=(1,i)(1,i+1)(j)=(1,i)(j)=j$$
for $j\neq i,i+1,1$.
So the transpositions starting in $1$ generate $S_n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, seems right to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd prove it by noticing $(1,i)(1,j)(1,i)=(i,j)$